# I turned off server 2012 which host my dhcp server but computers on the network still getting ip addresses

Tags: networking, dhcp

I have a DHCP server installed on Win Server 2012 which is turned off right now, but my computers still can establish online connections with the IPs previously received from the DHCP server.

I tried turning the network connection off and on again on the clients, but it ends up with the same IP all the time.

Is the IP somehow memorized by the computer?

Comment: Do you have a router giving out leases?

Answer (score 4):

Stopping the DHCP server won't prevent DHCP clients from using the DHCP assigned ip addresses that they have already leased from the DHCP server.

Answer (score 3):

A client that received an IP via DHCP has a lease on the provided IP.
by Default it works the following way: After 50% usage of the leasetime the client sends out an Request to the DHCP registered to. If this was unsuccessful the client will try again after 87% of the leasetime has passed, if the DHCP is still not reachable it'll send a broadcast searching for ANY available DHCP in the network. To manually delete the lease you can perform "ipconfig /release" and to manually request an IP "ipconfig /renew", by using "ipconfig /all" you'll be able to see which DHCP Server the client is bonded to.
If you see an IP 169.x.x.x no DHCP was found and an APIPA address been chosen, the client will continue in intervals searching via broadcast for a DHCP.

Comment: The `CIDR` for `LINKLOCAL-RFC3927-IANA-RESERVED` is `169.254.0.0/16`, not `169.0.0.0/8`.